# Why can't z3 solve this seemingly simple uninterpreted function problem?

Tags: z3, smt

Why is z3 unable to sat check the following?

```
(declare-fun f (Int) Int)
(assert (forall ((a Int) (b Int)) (= (+ (f a) (f b) ) (f (+ a b)))))
(assert (= (f 1) 1))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

I would expect a result along the lines of `f(x) = x`, however z3 seems to consume an increasing amount of ram, and never find a solution. 
Is this something uninterpreted functions are not intended for?

I've tried using reals and adding an additional function which I expect is the same as f, like so:

```
(declare-fun f (Real) Real)
(declare-fun g (Real) Real)
(assert (forall ((a Real)) (= (g a) a)))
(assert (forall ((a Real) (b Real)) (= (+ (f a) (f b) ) (f (+ a b)))))
(assert (= (f 1) 1))


(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's not simple at all. Quantifiers are hard, and as you suspected, SMT solvers are not a good choice for reasoning with them. In your particular case, the model finder would have to find a very specific kind of function that has that property, and that is well beyond capabilities of current SMT solving technology; and honestly the focus.

Having said that, you can look into quantifier patterns: You can help the e-matching engine in certain cases to solve such problems, but it's definitely not the right technology. See here: https://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorialcontent/guide#h28